# Creating a column of working days in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, date

In LibreOffice Calc, I would like to create a column of working days, like **Date** from below:

| Date | Day of week |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-01-30 | **Monday** |
| 2012-01-27 | Friday |
| 2012-01-26 | Thursday |
| 2012-01-25 | Wednesday |
| 2012-01-24 | Tuesday |
| 2012-01-23 | **Monday** |
| 2012-01-20 | Friday |
| 2012-01-19 | Thursday |
| 2012-01-18 | Wednesday |
| 2012-01-17 | Tuesday |
| 2012-01-16 | **Monday** |

Comment: Could you perhaps list anything you've already tried so we know what didn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be new since the question, but (LibreOffice 4.2.7.2 on Linux), Edit->Fill->Series. Choose Date as the series type and Weekday as the Time unit. I found that, after the fill, I had to select the filled cells and Format->Cells to select date formatting. (The original fill was a series of numbers.)

EDIT: Step-by-step instructions, as requested, this is now on 4.2.8.2, although I'm sorry I can't help with Windows:

- Select the range you want to fill. Start with it completely empty.
- Edit menu, Fill, Series
- Select "Down" under Direction, "Date" under Series type, and "Weekday" under Time unit.
- Enter the starting date in Start value (I used YYYY-MM-DD). End value blank, Increment 1.
- Click OK.
- Cells are now filled with numbers and selected.
- Format menu, Cells...
- Numbers tab, "Date" under category, choose whatever you want under "Format", click OK.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (4.3.2.2 on Windoze), could you please write a walkthroug step by step? I tried on empty cells (I selected 21 cells), I tried to enter 1/05/2015 in first cell (Polish date notation) and setting formatting to 'date'. I also tried filling first and second cell in column with next dates. Nothing worked for me

Comment: On `5.x` this menu has been moved to : `Sheet -> Fill cells -> Series`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you already have a similar range of dates then you can get the range you want by using the technique described in the accepted answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/299174/adding-a-constant-in-libreoffice-calc).

For example, addding "168:00" (168 hours = 1 week) to

2012-01-23 [Monday]
2012-01-20
2012-01-19
2012-01-18
2012-01-17
2012-01-16 [Monday]

gives you

2012-01-30 [Monday]
2012-01-27
2012-01-26
2012-01-25
2012-01-24
2012-01-23 [Monday]